# How do I call more than 100 statuses with Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a Facebook application and I want it to be able to read all the user's statuses from the past year. When I make the API call, I can only retrieve the first 100 statuses no matter what I set the limit to.

Here's the URL I'm using to make the call:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/statuses?limit=100&access_token=...

When I set the limit lower, it shows fewer statuses (proving that the limit argument works). When I set the limit higher, it only gives me the first 100. When I use 'since', it still only gives me 100.

When I use the 'next' url it gives me, I see no data past the first 100 statuses.

I know it's possible to get much more than that because of applications such as [My Year In Status](https://apps.facebook.com/my-year-in-status/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've verified using the Graph API explorer that the pagination is not working as you have described.  Log it as a bug with Facebook at: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs and post the bug # here.

**EDIT**

Per the bug closure, the 100 limit is **By Design** and you won't get more than that, meaning that Facebook has made a **conscious business decision** to **limit the amount of data** it has to **store, process, and serve** from the Graph API. It costs money to do so and since the API is free to use, I can't argue with them.  However, if I was paying for it, then hell yes I kick and scream all the way down the road.

Comment: Ray from Facebook said that you could only see 100 statuses _at once_ by design, but you can use pagination to see more. However, the pagination doesn't work, so his answer did not hold up. Anyway, it's been reassigned so they're working on it. He never said it's by design that you should only be able to retrieve 100 statuses.

Comment: And pagination is also a known bug too.  So with both a limit of 100, and not able to do accurate pagination, then you're stuck at 100 my friend. And that is the answer to your question.  Just because an answer to a question is "It's a bug", doesn't invalidate the answer from being correct.  Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for how to accept answers

Comment: I was able to get e.g. 379 statuses with Bill's technique.

Answer (score 6):

It does work. You must use both the `limit` and `offset` query parameters. The `limit` parameter sets the batch size. The `offset` parameter sets the position in the user's all-time status collection. Without specifying the `offset` parameter, Facebook defaults it to zero, which is why you keep seeing the same dataset.

For the 1st batch of 100 statuses, set `limit` to `100` and `offset` to `0`.
For the 2nd batch of 100 statuses, set `limit` to `100` and `offset` to `100`.
For the 3rd batch of 100 statuses, set `limit` to `100` and `offset` to `200`.
For the 4th batch of 100 statuses, set `limit` to `100` and `offset` to `300`.
And so on...

Keep iterating until you get an empty dataset:

```
{
   "data": []
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Paging** and **Since**, **Until** parameters not working for me too.

But I found out, that I'm able get more then 100 statuses using **Offset** parameter.
Here is my code using **Facebook C# SDK**:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

string connection = "statuses";
string urltemplate = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/{0}?limit={1}&offset={2}";

int limit = 25;     //items on one page (Max is value 100)
int offset = 0;

var statuses = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(string.Format(urltemplate, connection, limit, offset));

while (statuses != null && statuses.ContainsKey("data") && ((Facebook.JsonArray)statuses["data"]).Count > 0)
{
    var dataItems = (Facebook.JsonArray)statuses["data"];

    foreach (Facebook.JsonObject item in dataItems)
    {
        //TODO: process item data
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item["message"]);
    }

    offset += limit;
    statuses = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(string.Format(urltemplate, connection, limit, offset));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked as of a week ago, our best bet to get this fixed is to post on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/155458081230560 so the facebook developers know how big of an issue this is.

Comment: looks like it's gaining some momentum. hopefully they'll fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook closed the previous bug without really testing to see that it didn't work.  I've made a new bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242235199184053

Comment: Actually, they didn't say that.  They said the 100 limit is by design. See my updated answer with the additional information.